# How can I type a function that receives dynamic argument and does recursion

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm having troubles figuring out how to type this utility function that can receive some data in any form of Object / Array / Number / String.

Then it calls its respective handler like `parseArray` which receives an array which then calls `parseData` on each item of the array.

So this function will pretty much get some data in any structure, and return the same structure with some parsing on it.

Would love some guidance on this one.

```
function parseData(data) {
  if (Array.isArray(data)) {
    return parseArray(data);
  }

  if (typeof data === 'object') {
    return parseObject(data);
  }

  if (typeof data === 'string') {
    return parseString(data);
  }

  return data;
}
```

Comment: So the result type is the same as the input type ?

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir You are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a generic function, and with the result type and the parameter type having the same generic type parameter:

```
function parseData<T>(data: T): T {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        return parseArray(data);
    }

    if (typeof data === 'object') {
        return parseObject(data);
    }

    if (typeof data === 'string') {
        return parseString(data);
    }

    return data;
}
```

Since the `parse*` function will take different argument types, you might need to go through `any` to return `T`:

```
function parseData<T>(data: T): T {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
        return parseArray(data as any) as any; 
    }

    if (typeof data === 'string') {
        return parseString(data as string) as any;
    }

    if (typeof data === 'object') {
        return parseObject(data);
    }

    return data;
}

function parseObject (data: any) : any {
    return data;
}
function parseArray<T>(data: T[]) : T[] {
    return data;
}
function parseString (data: string) : string {
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I've been trying this one but then I'm having troubles with my returns having to do things like

`return parseArray(data) as T & T[];`

I'm missing something

Comment: You need to do some type assertions to `any`

Comment: @donzul I added a full solution, you will need to type assert in `parseData` but at least the call site ewill work ok

Comment: Question, what is the drawback of doing something like `function parseArray<T>(data: T[]): T[]`?

Comment: @donzul I don't know of any drawbacks, at runtime the type parameters are erased so it really does not matter. At compile time, the compiler will check you are actually passing in an array, which might get in your way in some corner cases (like above) but it is easy to get around using type assertions.

Comment: But is there a difference in using `function parseArray<T>(data: T[]): T[]`  instead of  `function parseArray (data: any[]) : any[]`? 

In terms of type correction / good practices?

Comment: @donzul there is an advantage in terms of type flow, if you pass in a number array you will get back a number array with the generic function. With the `any` version you pass in a `number` array but you get back an `any` array, so you loose type safety after the call

Comment: @donzul I changed to parseArray to be generic, in this case if you only use it in `parseData` it really makes no difference if it generic or not, that is why I didn't use the generic version

Answer (score 2):

> How can I type a function that receives dynamic argument and does recursion

It is essentially the same type as it is for `JSON.parse`.

You can use a generic type argument:

```
function parseData<T>(data)<T> {
}
```